# D7 forms: select values from a select list when a checkbox is checked using ajax

Tags: forms, ajax

In a node form I have 2 fields, the first one consisting in a list of regions, the second one consisting in a list of countries.

The needed behaviour is that when I click (let's say) "Africa" from the first list, all the countries belonging to Africa in the second list have to be selected.

This is the code in the hook_form_alter():

```
//add wrapper to the countries field
$form['field__country_multi']['#prefix'] = '<div id="multicountries">';
$form['field__country_multi']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

//add ajax behaviour to the regions field
$form['field__region_multi'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'preselect_countries_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'multicountries',
);
```

This is the callback function:

```
function preselect_countries_callback($form, $form_state) {
    //this returns an array of keys, I'm sure its structure is correct because 
    //if I put it directly in the form_alter the values are pre-selected correctly
    $africa = get_african_countries(); 

    //setting the #default value to the countries field. I tried even without
    //the LANGUAGE_NONE just because I ran out of ideas
    $form['field__country_multi'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $africa;

    //I tried even without the render() function wrapping the field object.
    return render($form['field__country_multi']);
}
```

What happens is that the wrapper is refreshed, but I noticed by inspecting the output that drupal is changing the id of the countries select list (from 'edit-field-country-multi-und' to 'edit-field-country-multi-und--2') and I guess that's why the values aren't being selected.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!